# Number and position recognition

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

Help with this image:

[image: Help with this image]

I want to extract the numbers (and the relative position of the number) from this image.
I'm using `pytesseract` with Python, but I can't obtain any result.
I don't know how to preprocess the image with `OpenCV`.

I need some help with pytesseract and openCV. Maybe some configuration for the method `image_to_strin`g from `pytesseract` ????

```
image = cv2.imread("plano5.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh,config='--psm 11 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
```

With this code, I can find all numbers and their positions EXCEPT the single digit numbers.

Comment: What you tried? Please show us your code and the results. Did you install tesseract in your machine? See instructions https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/

Comment: What does your image look like right after thresholding.  Can you visually distinguish your numbers?  Are the number black on white background?

Comment: `pytesseract` use C/C++ program `Tesseract` and in its documentation you can find instruction how to get better result. ie. it preferes black text on white background, text can't be too small, etc. I think `Tesseract` is good for normal text for book but not for maps.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes, my image has black numbers and white backgroud (the posted image is the original). All the numbers are perfectly visible in the processed image, but the code is returning me just the numbers whith two or more digits.

Comment: @furas Its working great! but I cant get the one digits numbers. Its giving me aprox 30 numbers (two and five digits), but no the single digits.

Comment: Dots may need to be larger in threshold to detect

Comment: maybe you should first use `OpenCV` to detect text on screen, next crop every text to separated image and later use `pytesseract to read text from every image. [OpenCV Text Detection (EAST text detector) - PyImageSearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/)

Answer (score 0):

I resized your image to 150% with GIMP. Than you can use the command:

```
tesseract.exe -l eng map_2.jpg out tsv
```

This get you a csv for **Libre Office Impress** or **Excel** which looks like my snap shot.
In the table you can find the position and in text column e.g 17, 90435, ... etc.. For details about tsv file see [here](https://blog.tomrochette.com/tesseract-tsv-format) or google it.

[image]